# SQL: Correctly identify and correct(if possible) names in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-like, identify

I have a large database of names, and I'm hoping to identify incorrect capitalization. 
Right now I'm using the following...

```
SELECT *
  FROM myTable
 WHERE LastName LIKE '%Mcd%'  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS
```

Now of course this is inefficent because I have to run/edit this over and over for different cases. My thinking is find a list of name cases that would provide possible problems, and do
    LIKE IN ('case1','case2','case3','case4', ...)

if that's possible. Is there another way that I'm not thinking of?

Other cases I'm thinking I'll have to check are abbreviations (%.%), hypens (%-%), and apostrophes (%'%).

Comment: `SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS` is SQL Server AFAIK but what version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
SELECT *
  FROM myTable
 WHERE LastName LIKE '%Mcd%' or LastName LIKE '%Foo%'
```

Or

```
WITH T(Word) AS
(
SELECT 'Mcd' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Foo'
)

SELECT *
FROM myTable
JOIN T ON LastName LIKE '%' + Word + '%'
```

To avoid needing to scan `myTable` multiple times.

To avoid processing *the string* multiple times you could use CLR and Regular Expressions.